# R Metaprop P-value overlapping with forest plot axes

Tags: r, statistics, meta-analysis

Trying to plot a forest plot using R Metaprop with the following code:

```
pes.summary  <- metaprop(`Events`, `Nodules`, `Author` , data = data , sm = "PFT", fixed = FALSE, random = TRUE, subgroup = Subgroup)
forest(pes.summary)
```

The code is working no problem, but the displayed p-value overlaps with the axis of the forest plot as shown in the picture below.

[image]

This specifically happens when I exclude either Random or Common effects model. When you print both, there ends up being enough spacing that there isn't any overlap, but just printing one causes the overlap seen here. How can I add a newline after Heterogeneity to avoid this overlap?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
forest(pes.summary, colgap.forest.left = "2cm")
```

I needed to add the `colgap` argument.